# Notepad++ replace(+1 number)

Tags: notepad++

I would like to have Notepad++ replace numbers, e.g. occurrences of  "1000", with automatic increment of +1. Is this possible in Notepad++?

For example replace the following:

```
- 1000
- 1000
- 1000
- 1000
- 1000
```

with this:

```
- 1001
- 1002
- 1003
- 1004
- 1005
```

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLNXz.png). I want to replace all 3673 numbers in order. i have at least 2,000 lines.

Comment: I would try to import file into excel or some other spreadsheet and modify the numbers there.

Comment: but the numbers are in code with different columns. it's written on C++ but i'm trying to edit it in Notepad++. any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the numbers with some real example lines (source and target) so we can help in a better way. Think about the idea of @Lars because it's a CSV format (Excel import and export as text for later use in your C++ IDE) .